# check if text vector contains a certain text in R

Tags: r, text, stringr, grepl

What is the best method to check to see if a text is in another variable in R? Below is an example:

```
a= 'homer simpson the third'
b= c('homer simpson','marge','bart')

grepl(a,b)
# this is what it returns
FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I am wanting it to return TRUE FALSE FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, use `agrep` with a custom value for the `max.distance`

```
agrepl(a, b, max.distance = 0.5)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The reason is that each element of `b` seems to be a substring of the 'a' pattern

Comment: that works! just found another way to do it as well using the stringr package. str_detect(a,b) produces TRUE FALSE FALSE as well.

Comment: @jsimpsno but that was just because you are using `b` as `pattern`.  Do the reverse as in `grepl` and it won't work i.e. `str_detect(b, a)#
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE`.  In `str_detect`, pattern is the second argument whereas in `grepl` it is the first